# Get selected cell rows from nested JMenuItems context menu (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jmenu, jmenuitem

Context: In my *Jtable*, I make a selection of multiple cells, and then perform a right-click. From the selected option in my sub-menu, I need to obtain the selected cell references.
I am able to get selected rows and columns from my popup menu, **but not from the nested or sub-menu**.

[image: Menu]

Here's my code snippets:

```
private JMenuItem menuItem1;
private JMenuItem makeMenuItem(String label) {
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(label);
    item.addActionListener(this);
    return item;
}

JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.add(makeMenuItem("Menu1"));
popup.add(makeMenuItem("Menu2"));

JMenu menuItem = new JMenu("Sub-menu");
menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Sub-1");
menuItem.add(menuItem1);
menuItem1.addActionListener(this);
```

....

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == menuItem1){
        //I am unable to get the selected rows and columns
        JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,source.getClass().getName() );
    }else{

    Component com = (Component)e.getSource();
    JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)com.getParent();
    JTable table = (JTable)popup.getInvoker();

    //I am able to get selected rows and columns over here.
    int row[] = table.getSelectedRows();
    int col[] = table.getSelectedColumns();
    }
}
```

For the primary menu (menu1 & menu2), I am able to get the selected rows and columns via "(JTable)popup.getInvoker();" which unfortunately does not work with JMenuItems. The if else statement, as well as the image, is just for illustration purpose. For your advice, thanks.

Comment: Can't you just store the selection before popup menu showing and use this from the actionPerformed()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "(JTable)popup.getInvoker();" which unfortunately does not work with JMenuItems.

You are already using the `getParent()` method. You just can't assume that the JPopupMenu is the first parent.

You need to create a while loop that keeps getting the parent of the menu item until you find the popup menu. Then you can access the invoker.

Comment: thanks. I've tried the loop but I'm getting Null Pointer on the different levels of .getParent().

Comment: hey, it now works with some casting. Thanks for your help. Will post my answer for reference, and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @camickr and [this post on parent frame of JMenuItem](http://www.coderanch.com/t/346777/GUI/java/parent-frame-JMenuItem-ActionListener). Here's what works (code for illustration):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    try{
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) e.getSource(); 
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) menuItem.getParent(); 
        Component invoker = popupMenu.getInvoker();      
        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu) invoker.getParent();
        JTable table = (JTable)popup.getInvoker();
        int row[] = table.getSelectedRows();
        int col[] = table.getSelectedColumns();
        System.out.println("Test print: "+row[0]+"-"+col[0]);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using jMenu.setName("jMenu1") and source.getParent().getName() and was helpful in debugging.